# Как грамотно интегрировать чужой проект из гитхаба в свой?

Tags: c++, github, cmake, library

На эту тему написано уже много всего, да и я сам уже добавлял в свой код сторонние гитхаб-проекты, но в этот раз я столкнулся с проблемой.

**Что имею:**

Понадобилась такая штука, как libpcap, вернее часть ее исходного кода. Клонировал [репозиторий](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap), добавил папку в проект с помощью Cmake.

Содержимое CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(Imap)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(Imap main.cpp Headers.h glib.h ImapReader.cpp ImapReader.h)

include_directories(/home/alex/libpcap)
target_link_libraries(Imap "/home/alex/libpcap")
```

**Суть проблемы:**

Программа падает на этапе компиляции с сообщением:

```
CMakeFiles/Imap.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/alex/CLionProjects/Imap/main.cpp:39: undefined reference to `pcap_open_offline'
/home/alex/CLionProjects/Imap/main.cpp:59: undefined reference to `pcap_next_ex'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/Imap.dir/build.make:98: recipe for target 'Imap' failed
make[3]: *** [Imap] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Imap.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Imap.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:84: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Imap.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Imap.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'Imap' failed
make: *** [Imap] Error 2
```

Т.е. компилятор не видит файл, в котором содержатся тела данных функций, хотя он находится в подключенной папке.

Структура папки:

libpcap:

- Файлы исходного кода вперемешку со всякой всячиной
- Несколько незначащих(для меня) папок
- Папка с заголовочными файлами (/pcap)

Подскажите, как грамотно сконфигурировать Cmake?

Comment: А что сабмодули гита отменили? Как минимум форканите библиотеку которая Вам нужна. Создайте репо с Вашим проектом и библиотечкой в виде сабмодулей. В CMake просто заинклюживайте то, что Вам нужно. Или напишите скрипт сборки ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`target_link_libraries(Imap "/home/alex/libpcap")` не занимается сборкой проекта, в лучшем случае компилятор узнает где хедеры искать. Поэтому компилятор справедливо замечает, что от него хотят странного.

> Как грамотно интегрировать чужой проект из гитхаба в свой?

- озадачится скриптом/использовать менеджер пакетов ([vcpkg, conan и пр.](https://habr.com/ru/post/342982/)), которые соберут и установят зависимости.

Поскольку `pcap` это CMake проект, собрать его не составит проблем - всё как обычно:

```bsh
cmake "<source path>" <CMAKE GENERATOR> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<install path>
cmake --build . --target install
```

тогда `CMakeList.txt` мог бы содержать следующее:

```
find_package(pcap)
add_executable(Imap <sources>)
target_link_libraries(Imap pcap::pcap)
```

"Мог бы", потому что [`pcap`](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) не экспортирует файл конфигурации как положено, вместо этого куча кода на генерацию `libpcap.pc`. Поэтому, либо писать свой `FindPcap.cmake`, либо использовать [`pkg-config`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/module/FindPkgConfig.html)

- включить в свой проект как модуль.

Не для всякого проекта такое возможно, но если получится, тогда `CMakeList.txt` будет содержать следующее:

```
add_subdirectory(3rdparty/pcap)
add_executable(Imap <sources>)
target_link_libraries(Imap pcap)
```

Для `pcap` я бы рекомендовал добавить в начале `set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)` - меньше шансов, что у цели `pcap` будут пропущены ссылки на зависимости.

#### Как не надо делать:

Mожно, но не стоит, включать исходники чужого проекта в сборку своего. Это редко, но бывает, что сторонняя либа хорошо разбита на независимые блоки кода и тогда можно попытаться добавить нужные

```
add_executable(Imap <sources> <list of 3rdparty/pcap/*.c>)
```

Если есть желание помучиться, то добавьте одну единицу компиляции к `Imap` а затем на каждый `undefined reference to` ищите в каком файле лежит реализация и добавляйте его. И, кстати, когда добавите весь набор `3rdparty/pcap/*.c`, не удивляйтесь, что не соберётся или будет падать - ещё придётся угадать правильные дефайны и сделать правильные хедеры, которые обычно генерируются.

Answer (score 0):

Если пользуетесь `cmake` и `git`, то лучшее что можно сделать, это отвести для включаемого проекта (или проектов) отдельную папку (обычно она называется `third-party`) в которой добавите включаемый проект как СУБМОДУЛЬ `git`. Это позволит без проблем обновлять включаемый проект. Что касается `cmake`, то у вас сдесь ошибка: `target_link_libraries` принимает библеотеку, которую нужно прилинковать, а вы указываете папку. Если `libpcap` поддерживает `cmake`, то, скорее всего, достаточно будет просто включить его как `subdirectory`  в `CMakeLists.txt`, а в `target_link_libraries` указать цель из `cmake` включаемого проекта.

PS не используйте `include_directories`, вместо этого используйте `target_include_directories`. Не забывайте о спецификаторах `PUBLIC` `PRIVATE`, а стандард указывайте с помощью `target_compile_features`